# Function reuse in android

Tags: java, android, oop, multiple-inheritance, code-reuse

I have a native android application with about 20 Classes for 10 Activities.

I want to reuse a function definition in every Activity. I have a bottom bar and clicking on it from any activity should trigger this function. Since Java cant have multiple inheritance, how do i copy this function to where ever i want?

Comment: If Java had support for "multiple inheritance", how would you use it to solve this issue?

Comment: @βнɛƨнǤʋяʋиɢ, obvious way is to extend Activity and another class, that has all required functions.

Comment: @user826788 AFAIK, Android apps need one Activity/Class per screen/view. Hence 10 Activities can be justified. Had to write classes for Image download, JSON parsing, Autofill extra.

Comment: @Jaseem You can still edit an activity "live", so that you only need one class, although in all likelihood that's bad practice. I don't think you should be restricted to a conventional style though. Besides, can't you just have lots of Views and one Activity?I wasn't being completely facetious so it's frustrating that my comments were removed without explanation or warning. Undeletion would be welcome.

Comment: @user826788 It was not me who deleted it by the way. I am a novice android programmer and this is what i figured out from the documentation.

Comment: @biovamp: IMHO, you are thinking the opposite way. This is a case of generalization. He has several related classes with same behaviors on all of them. But, since they do not descend from the same ancestor, he has the same piece of code scattered all over the place. So, he want's to generalize and come up with a base class.

Comment: @Jaseem I know. Didn't mean to direct it at you. I'll complain on meta...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make `BasicActivity` class and extend it from `Activity` and write that method inside it.

and now extend every `Activity` in your application from `BasicActivity`

Comment: And for more clarity when you reread your code, BasicActivity should be abstract.

Comment: Problem solved. Any better alternatives ?

Comment: @Jaseem without knowing any details, impossible to say.

Answer (score 1):

Another method is to create class, that have all functions that you're need. You can use singleton pattern for such thing.

---

Example:

```
public final class SingletonClass{
    private SingletonClass(){}

    private static class InstanceHolder{
        private static final SingletonClass instance=new SingletonClass();
    }

    public static SingletonClass getInstance(){
        return InstanceHolder.instance;
    }

    /*your public non-static methods here*/
}
```

And then:

```
SingletonClass singleton=SingletonClass.getInstance();
singleton.someMethod();
```